# Trying to show a div if the input value of a form field is empty, using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

Hello I am working with bootstrap trying to show a warning-div when login/password not filled but it seems like it shows but hide again so not showing at all, here is the code:

```
<head>
    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script language="javaScript">  
        var namePattern = "^[a-z A-Z]{4,30}$";
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#bEnviar").click(function(){
                var login = $("#login").val();
                var password = $("#password").val();
                if( login=="" ){
                    $("#login").css("display","block");
                }
                if( password="" ){
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="">
        <div class="form-group col-md-12">
            <label for="login" class="col-form-label">Login</label>
            <input type="text" id="login" class="form-control" placeholder="Login">             
            <div id="login" class="alert alert-danger d-none" role="alert-danger">
                Inserte nombre de usuario
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-12">
            <label for="password" class="col-form-label">Password</label>
            <input type="password" id="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
            <div id="pass" class="alert alert-danger d-none" role="alert-danger">
                Inserte password
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-12"> 
            <button type='submit' id="bEnviar" class="btn btn-primary">Ingresar</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

Javascript is working fine cus i tried an alert and when i press submit button it shows.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You have two elements with they same id `login`. it is forbidden and cause wrong results. maybe change one of `id`s to something else and try again. You have also two elements with id `password`, change one them too.

Comment: This line is incorrect, it should be an equality operator. `if( password="" `

Answer (score 2):

You have 3 main errors in your code:

1. There are 2 elements with the same id `login`.
2. If you want to check your input before submit, you shouldn't use `type="submit"` because it will submit the form anyway when you click the button. Use `type="button"` if use want to check your input first.
3. Class `d-none` has css `display: none!important;` so you need to remove it if you want the div to display.

Here's the code after fixed these errors:

```js
var namePattern = "^[a-z A-Z]{4,30}$";

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#bEnviar").click(function(){
            var login = $("#login").val();
            var password = $("#password").val();

            if(!login) {
                $("#login_error").removeClass("d-none");
            } else $("#login_error").addClass("d-none");
            if(!password) {
                $("#pass").removeClass("d-none");
            } else $("#pass").addClass("d-none");
            
            if (login && password) {
              // Submit form
            }
        });

    });
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<form action="">
            <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                <label for="login" class="col-form-label">Login</label>
                <input type="text" id="login" class="form-control" placeholder="Login">             
                <div id="login_error" class="alert alert-danger d-none" role="alert-danger">
                    Inserte nombre de usuario
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                <label for="password" class="col-form-label">Password</label>
                <input type="password" id="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
                <div id="pass" class="alert alert-danger d-none" role="alert-danger">
                    Inserte password
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-12"> 
                <button type='button' id="bEnviar" class="btn btn-primary">Ingresar</button>
            </div>

        </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

change this

```
<div id="login_error" class="alert alert-danger d-none" role="alert-danger">
```

and then in javascript you have to use

```
$("#login_error").css("display","block");
```

as two elements can not have same id. You are using login id in input as well as in div which will not work.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 main things you need to fix.

First make the form action point to the same page. When action="" it reloads the page, when action="#" it points to something within the page.

second, your logic for if (password = "") should be if (password === "") notice assignment vs. comparison.

Then you just need to remove the d-none class from your id=pass div

Here's a working version of your code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
  <form action="#">
    <div class="form-group col-md-12">
        <label for="login" class="col-form-label">Login</label>
        <input type="text" id="login" class="form-control" placeholder="Login">
        <div id="login" class="alert alert-danger d-none" role="alert-danger">
            Inserte nombre de usuario
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group col-md-12">
        <label for="password" class="col-form-label">Password</label>
        <input type="password" id="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
        <div id="pass" class="alert alert-danger d-none" role="alert-danger">
            Inserte password
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-12">
        <button type='submit' id="bEnviar" class="btn btn-primary">Ingresar</button>
    </div>

</form>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <script>

      var namePattern = "^[a-z A-Z]{4,30}$";

      $(document).ready(function(){
          $("#bEnviar").click(function(){
            console.log('clicked #bEnviar');
              var login = $("#login").val();
              var password = $("#password").val();

              if( login === "" ){
                  $("#login").css("display","block");

              }
              if( password === "" ){
                $("#pass").removeClass('d-none');

              }
          });

      });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi the page is reloading as the form is getting submitted. You need to prevent the form from getting submitted in case of error.

You can either use `event.preventDefault()` or `return false`

Also, the ID needs to be unique for each element. You are using the "login" as id for both the message div and the input element.

Hope the below code snippet helps.

```js
var namePattern = "^[a-z A-Z]{4,30}$";

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#bEnviar").click(function(event) {
    debugger;
    var login = $("#login").val();
    var password = $("#password").val();

    if (login === "") {
      $("#login-err").removeClass("d-none");
      // use prevent default or return false
      event.preventDefault()
      return false;
    }
    if (password === "") {
      $("#password-err").removeClass("d-none");
      // use prevent default or return false
      event.preventDefault()
      return false;
    }
  });

});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<form action="">
  <div class="form-group col-md-12">
    <label for="login" class="col-form-label">Login</label>
    <input type="text" id="login" class="form-control" placeholder="Login">
    <div id="login-err" class="alert alert-danger d-none" role="alert-danger">
      Inserte nombre de usuario
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group col-md-12">
    <label for="password" class="col-form-label">Password</label>
    <input type="password" id="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
    <div id="password-err" class="alert alert-danger d-none" role="alert-danger">
      Inserte password
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-md-12">
    <button type='submit' id="bEnviar" class="btn btn-primary">Ingresar</button>
  </div>

</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

The main reason why it is appearing and then disappearing is because your form is getting submitted by default. You need to prevent that by passing the `event` to the `click` function and then calling `event.preventDefault()`, before trying to change the display style.

Another point to note is the use of 1 `id` for multiple elements. `IDs` are unique, thus `1 ID` per element. So, you should also rename your error `divs` perhaps to `login_error` and `password_error`.

So, you `jquery` should look thus:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#bEnviar").click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();    //Prevent forms default behaviour
            var login = $("#login").val();
            var password = $("#password").val();

            // If the login value is not set
            if (!login) {
                $("#login_error").css("display", "block"); // This overrides d-none and makes it display
            }
            // If the password value is not set
            if (!password) {
                $("#password_error").css("display", "block");
            }
        });

    });
```

Since the `action` attribute in your `form` is empty, you can do away with it and just have `<form></form>`

I assumed that `d-none` in your `html` translates to `display-none` and sets the `display` of the `error divs` to `none`. If not, you have to first set the `error divs` to display `none` in your `css` before your `script` fires and sets them to display `block`.
The CSS below should do that:

```
    <style>
        .form-group #password_error,
        .form-group #login_error {
            display: none;
        }
    </style>
```